# Is the Time Complexity of this code O(N)?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is the Time Complexity of this code O(N) ?
(in this code I want to find Kth largest element of array)

```
class Solution {
    public:
        int findKthLargest(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
            make_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end());
            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i ++) {
                pop_heap(nums.begin(), nums.end());
                nums.pop_back();
            }
            return nums.front();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your loop? How does it find the k-th largest element?

Comment: @patatahooligan The algorithm removes the biggest number for (k-1) times, then return the biggest number remaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Depends.

Because `make_heap` is already at O(n), and each loop is at O(log n), the total time complexity for your algorithm is **O(n + k log n)**. With a small k or a "good" set of data, the result is roughly O(n) and the constant behind the O() mark, but with a large k (near or surpassing n/2) or random data, it's O(n log n).

Also I'd like to point out that this code is modifying the original array (using reference for passing arguments), which isn't often a good practice.

<sup>log is 2-based in this post</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is proplem with "using reference for passing arguments" ?

Comment: Passing by reference allows you to modify (and you do) the *original* data, which is not a calculating (instead of modifying) function intended to do.